# How can I rotate pictures on my website?

Tags: javascript, html, web, image

Is there standard code I can use to rotate pictures in my HTML website?

Comment: You mean rotating in terms of editing? Have you googled?

Comment: Yes editing. i have googled it and out comes many different codes which is not similar at all

Comment: there are hundreds of javaScript libraries to choose from that use jQuery/MoooooToools.. some API sites.. and then you got HTML5/CSS3 .. nothing simple for all browsers.. soz

Comment: I'm using a mac, text wrangler and i am a noob/beginner at this html coding. I need a code to place in my website codes so that some of my pictures will face the right way up instead of it being tilted.

Answer (score 3):

CSS3 has a `transform` style, which allows you to rotate any HTML element. You'd use it like this:

```
.myelement {
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

This should work in the latest versions of most browsers (Firefox 5, Chrome 13, IE9, etc). However, older browsers will have issues.

Some older browsers require vendor prefixes, so you'd need `-moz-transform` and `-webkit-transform`, etc.

Older versions of IE didn't support the `transform` style at all, but they do have a `filter` attribute which can be used instead. Unfortunately, IE's filter syntax for rotation is rather complex. You have to specify a matrix transform, with the values in radians rather than degrees, so it can be a bit obscure.

For a 45 degree rotation, you'd use the following code:

```
.myelement {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.70710678, M12=-0.70710678, M21=0.70710678, M22=0.70710678,sizingMethod='auto expand')";
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.70710678, M12=-0.70710678, M21=0.70710678, M22=0.70710678,sizingMethod='auto expand');
}
```

You'll note that IE6 and IE7 require the `filter` style, whereas IE8 requires `-ms-filter` (with slightly different syntax).

Rather than explain it here, I'll point you to a page where it is explained in detail: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/

One final note of caution on the `filter` style: The IE6/7 syntax is invalid CSS (due to the colon after `progid`, among other things). I have seen it actually cause other browsers (notably Firefox 3.6) to fail to parse the entire stylesheet. For this reason, I recommend using it in a separate IE-specific stylesheet which you can exclude entirely from other browsers.

If you want to do it via Javascript, I'd recommend using a JQuery plug in. This will remove the complexity of having to write separate code for all the different browsers. See here for more info: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/rotate

Hope that helps.

Comment: As per robertc’s comment below, for CSS rotations in IE using `filter`, see http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/transforms/matrix-calculator.html

Comment: @Paul - the boogdesign page is good for producing working styles for IE, but it also produces Matrix transforms for all other browsers too. Granted that does mean it's the same numbers in all browsers, but wouldn't a `rotate()` transform as per my answer be much simpler? (and probably less work for the browser).

Comment: oh yeah, `rotate()`’s definitely simpler. But folks do need to know about the `filter` stuff if they want to provide the rotation in IE8 as well, so (until older IEs die off) it’s worth mentioning. (Whether it’s worth *using* `filter` depends on the project’s context.)

Answer (score 2):

You rotate images either on the client-side (within the browser) or server-side (in your server and then re-send the image to the browser).

To rotate on the browser, see Spudley's answer.

The common way on the server is to use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) Most all web languages/frameworks include bindings to enable easy use of image magick. Eg here's the [PHP version](https://www.php.net/imagick).

[A list](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php) for many different languages.

You can use Ajax techniques to rotate the image for the user without requiring a page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only support for rotating HTML elements is provided by CSS transforms.

They were invented by the WebKit team (I think):

- http://www.webkit.org/blog/130/css-transforms/

There is now support in other browsers too:

- http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/